# How to increase maximum Docker Network on one server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

In my computer, I can create more maximum 29 `Docker Network`, like that.

```
for num in `seq -w 100`; do
    echo "Create network: $num"
    docker network create $num
done
```

After creating 29 `Docker Network`, I get error:

```
Error response from daemon: failed to parse pool request for address space "LocalDefault" pool "" subpool "": could not find an available predefined netw
ork
```

**My Question:** How to increase maximum Docker Network on one server?

Because I used to test many docker-compose should require more network.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For every network, docker reserves a private IP pool and reserves a range of IP addresses.

Private address range is defined here(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

Docker uses following pool:

172.17.0.0/16 - 172.31.0.0/16 - 15

192.168.0.0/20 - 192.168.224.0/20 - 15

Default bridge network takes up 1. Thats why you see the limit at 29. This limit does not apply for other networks like overlay.

Comment: The question is how to increase the maximum amount of networks available for docker so this should not be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to extend network limit without breaking existing containers/networks edit: `/etc/docker/daemon.json`:

```json
{
   "default-address-pools": [
        {
            "base":"172.17.0.0/12",
            "size":16
        },
        {
            "base":"192.168.0.0/16",
            "size":20
        },
        {
            "base":"10.99.0.0/16",
            "size":24
        }
    ]
}
```

(add values if not exists), then `sudo service docker restart`

First two are [default docker address pools,](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/8663) last is one of the [private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)

With this change you have additionally 255 networks. New containers attach to new address pool 10.99.0.0.

Comment: why would someone give so little default network size????????

Answer (score 1):

I used this guide: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ipv4_address-ipv6_address

I set a subnet like 172.10.10.0/24 uniquely for each docker-compose group.

/web1/ would have a docker-compose with 172.1.0.0/24
/web2/ would have a docker-compose with 172.2.0.0/24

Comment: It is not a good idea to use publicly routable addresses as addresses for your private subnets. [RFC 1918](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1918) describes `10/8`, `172.16/12` and `192.168/16` as private address ranges. So you may use anything between 172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255, for example. But 172.10.*, 172.1.* and 172.2.* are addresses routable on the internet.