# How to allow specific containers to communicate while Docker disables communication between containers

Tags: docker

For security reasons, I need to disable communication between containers. My first thought was to put each container in a custom network, but the number of subnets is limited (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609998/how-to-increase-maximum-docker-network-on-one-server)). For this I learned about the usage of "icc=false"

In addition, I also need to allow some containers to communicate, which requires using the "link" method when "icc=false", but "link" is unsafe and will be deprecated. Of course I can use custom network, but what I am concerned about is still the quantity of networks.

In "icc=false" mode, network works fine, but only in 172.17.0.0/16 - 172.31.0.0/16. If I need hundreds of networks, what am I supposed to do?